In proof that number of incongruent integers of order $d$ modulo $p$ is equal to $\phi(d)$
I am reading the Kenneth H. Rosen's Elementary number theory, proof of the Theorem 9.8 and don't understand some statement clearly.

Theorem 9.8. Let $p$ be a prime and let $d$ be a positive divisor of $p-1$. Then the number of incongruent integers of order $d$ modulo $p$ is equal to $\phi(d)$.

Proof. For each positive divisor $d$ dividing $p-1$, let $F(d)$ denote the number of positive integers of order $d$ modulo $p$ that are less than $p$. Because the order modulo $p$ of an integer not divisible by $p$ divides $p-1$, it follows that
$$ p-1 = \Sigma_{d|p-1}F(d).$$
I don't understand the bold statement clearly. Can anyone explain the argument more friendly?
C.f. In the Thomas Koshy's Elementary number theory book, Theorem 10.6, he argues the statement in a slightly different way as follows :
For every positive factor $d$ of $p-1$, let $\psi(d)$ denote the number of positive residues modulo $p$ that have order $d$. Because there are $p-1$ positive residues and each has a unique order $d$, the positive residues of order $d$ form a partitioning of the set of positive residues. Therefore, $\Sigma_{d|p-1} \psi(d) = p-1$.
$\divideontimes$ Additional question : Can we prove the Theorem 9.8 above by using cyclic group theory?
Can anyone help?

You might find this helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)

Let $a$ be an integer not divisible by $p$, and let $d$ be its order modulo $p$. The bold statement is basically saying that, in this scenario, $d\mid p-1$, which follows from the fact that $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ (by Fermat's Little Theorem) and that, for any integer $k$, we have:

$a^k\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ if and only if $d\mid k$.

So, the bold statement could be expressed in this "more friendly way":

Any nonzero residue modulo $p$ has an order which is a divisor of $p-1$. Therefore, if we classify these nonzero residues by their order, we get a disjoint union $\displaystyle{\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\setminus\left\{0\right\}=\bigcup_{d\mid p-1}G_{d}}$, where $G_d$ is the set of nonzero residues modulo $p$ having order $d$. By taking cardinality on this equality, we get $\displaystyle{p-1=\sum_{d\mid p-1}F\left(d\right)}$.

Hopefully that's better. Observe that the other exposition of the proof you shared is using the same fact quoted above, because the author is restricting only to the divisors of $p-1$, which is valid because no nonzero residue modulo $p$ can have an order that does not divide $p-1$, so he is sure that he is not omitting any possibility.

Thanks ! ~~~~~~
